# After the latest update (1703), my start-menu is disabled in Windows 10. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

After installing the update 1703, I can no longer use the start-menu. Luckily I have an alternative launcher installed (Launchy) which at least lets me use the computer. But I'm stuck for things that Launchy cannot find.

The symptom is that I can still open the start-menu itself, but it looks like it's disabled. The items look semi-transparent, and I can neither click not type text to use the "search" feature.

After googling, I tried to run `sfc /scannow` from a privileged PowerShell, but it reported no errors. Rebooting did not help either.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

*update:* I tried logging in with another account. That account also already existed *before* the upgrade. When logging in with that account I got a message that some upgrades were being installed. I did not get that message with my normal account. Is it possible that something is left unconfigured after the upgrade? In any case, with that second account, the start-menu is working properly. I wouldn't mind keeping my usual account. Is there a possibility to "reset" just the start-menu for that account?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, it seems that **it was due to low disk-space** on my main drive (the one where Windows is installed). I *assume* that the updates did not apply correctly.

I noticed that the ActionCenter contained a warning that some updates could not be installed correctly, even tough the "Settings/Updates" tab showed all the updates as "successful".

After freeing up disk-space, I noticed that the service host had elevated activity on the network (via the task manager). This usually means that some updates are downloading.

After a while the svchost calmed down again and the start-menu magically started working again. Even without rebooting.

Unfortunately I can only give an educated guess as to what happened. I guess some files got corrupted to to low disk space causing this error (and potentially others as well which I did not run into). I'm surprised that `sfc` did not pick up on that. Or maybe the update simply did not finish properly. It never could recover as there was not enough disk-space available. After freeing up disk-space, the recovery could take place and fix the problem at hand.